# Angular2 how to remove 1 specific element from list with mouseclick

Tags: javascript, angular

I am having a small issue in my code. Ive created an weather application using angular 2 and it works fine. Though do i have a small problem when clicking "delete this city button" where it delets only the last city in and not the one I wanted, how can i solve this? Here is my code:

```
clearWeatherItems() {

    for(WEATHER_ITEMS, function(i)){
       var city = WEATHER_ITEMS[i];

       if(city == WEATHER_ITEMS[i]) {

        city.splice(i, 1);
        return false;

       }
     }

    } }
```

Ive also tried doing it this way but still the same problem occurs:

```
clearWeatherItems() {
        WEATHER_ITEMS.splice(-1);

    }
```

here is my weather-item.component.ts:

```
import { Component, Input } from 'angular2/core';
import { WeatherItem } from "./weather-Item";

@Component({
    selector: 'weather-item',
    template: `
        <div id="clear">
        </div>
        <article class="weather-element">
            <div class="col-1">
                <h3>{{ weatherItem.cityName }}</h3>
                <p class="info">{{ weatherItem.description }}</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-2">
                <span class="temperature">{{ weatherItem.temprature }}°C</span>
            </div>
            <button class="delete" (click)="clearWeatherItems($event, weatherItem)">X</button>
        </article>
    `,
    styleUrls: ['src/css/weather-item.css'],
   // inputs: ['weatherItem: item']
})
export class WeatherItemComponent {
   @Input('item') weatherItem: WeatherItem; 

   clearWeatherItems() {
       // event.stopPropagation();


        this.weatherItem.clearWeatherItems();

   }

}
```

my weather.data.ts:

```
import { WeatherItem } from "./weather-Item";

export const WEATHER_ITEMS: WeatherItem[] = [];
```

and here is my weather-item.ts:

```
import { WEATHER_ITEMS } from "./weather.data";

export class WeatherItem {


    constructor(public cityName, public description: string, public temprature: number) {



    }
    clearWeatherItems(item) {
        WEATHER_ITEMS.splice(-1);


    }
}
```

Somebody knows what to do?

Best regards from a programming noob :P

Comment: the code looks really bad. I would rather expect method like `clearWeatherItem(item)` to be called onclick.

Comment: I have also tried doing this this way.. Didnt work..

Comment: Why do you have a weatherItem class here? Remove it, no need for a class here or a class specific method. Just have an interface and handle the deletion in the component like Sajeetharan suggested :)

Comment: I writed this :   

clearWeatherItem(item){
   let index: number = this.WEATHER_ITEMS.indexOf(item);
    if (index !== -1) {
        this.data.splice(index, 1);
    }      
} 
}

I get an red line under "this.WEATHER_ITEMS" where error says : "[ts] Property 'WEATHER_ITEMS' does not exist on type 'WeatherItem'."

Without this i dont get any red lines, but still it doesnt work ..

Comment: Where have you put this code?

Comment: Is this a child component since you are using `@Input`?

Comment: Ive tried this both in my "weather-item.component.ts" code and also in "weather-item.ts". check my first post which I`ve edited :)

It is not important if it is child class or not.. Ive tried everything.

Comment: @raxor Of course this is important. You are nowhere even showing an array from where you are deleting this item? Where is the array in template? The template you are showing just has one weather item.

Answer (score 1):

Just declare a method on ts file

```
clearWeatherItem(item:any){
   let index: number = this.WEATHER_ITEMS.indexOf(item);
    if (index !== -1) {
        this.data.splice(index, 1);
    }      
}
```

call this method by passing the item to be removed from the HTML template